# which is better for desktop application?

Tags: apache-flex, flex3, air, desktop-application

i'm new to creating desktop applications. I've a working site in php with mysql support. I want to *convert* this site into a desktop application. Is Adobe AIR or Adobe Flex better?
can i use php as such in both AIR and Flex? or should i convert them to xml or something which it uses?

Comment: I don't want to add another answer because the ones below cover the topic well, but regarding one point I wasn't sure on. Do you want your app to connect to a server? If your app stands alone and doesn't require a data connection for anything more than some settings or calculations then convert to XML and avoid the hassle of data connections.

Comment: i NEED to communicate with a server, thatz why i'm insisting on it. Otherwise i'd have used XML as u said.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AIR is Flex on the desktop... So... I suppose you mean whether you can use AIR with PHP? AIR/Flex should be able to handle whatever communication protocol you're using on the server.

Comment: Well, I found that the Adobe pages to be pretty useful, you can also check out http://blog.flexexamples.com/ for some more advanced examples. I was already familiar with programming when I started learning Flex, so I didn't really look at any tutorials on the programming side of things.

Comment: thanks CookieOfFortune ..but can i write FLEX application and then convert it to AIR?

Comment: yes. That should work out fine. I believe that's really what Adobe is trying to do with AIR/Flex, design for the web and desktop at the same time. There are some caveats but it should be fine overall.

Comment: AIR is Flash Player on the desktop. Flex can be used with both Flash Player and AIR, but it is not required.

Answer (score 1):

Saying 'should i convert them to xml or something' is a bit nebulous.

I guess what you really asking is: Should I rewrite my application entirely in Adobe technologies or Can I/Should I integrate it with my existing PHP code.

I would recommend you expose the existing PHP functionality as RESTful web services and redo the user interface in Adobe AIR.  That way you can leverage the existing site to make the desktop application.  There is a ton of information of building applications like this, just research REST, SOA (service oriented architecture), SAAS (Software as a Service).

Adobe AIR/Flex is fine, especially if you want it to work on multiple operating systems, but the Application won't necessary have the looking and feel of its host desktop environment.

Answer (score 1):

**Adobe AIR** is a runtime that adds to the capabilities of Adobe Flash Player to allow the creation of desktop applications.

**Adobe Flex** is a framework to build rich user interfaces. Flex applications are supported both in Flash Player and AIR.

This cannot be a question of one or the other. Flex can be used together *with* AIR. If you want a desktop app that allows you to use Adobe's Flash Platform technologies, definitely use AIR. If you want a set of pre-built UI controls to use in that AIR app, use Flex too!

You can communicate with PHP on your server in both Flash Player and AIR. PHP cannot be run directly in AIR. If you want the application to be entirely self-contained with no server, then you can't use PHP.